# SICCI for Xcode plug-in for Jenkins fails

Tags: xcode, build, hudson, jenkins

My Jenkins version is 1.399.  My Xcode version is 3.2.5.  Here is the Console Output.

```
Started by user anonymous
Updating svn://192.168.31.240/data/master/SVN/XXX/trunk/eMeeting
U         Classes/xxxxxxxxAppDelegate.m
U         Classes/DbUtils.h
U         Classes/DbUtils.m
U         Classes/ThumbnailCache.h
U         Classes/ThumbnailCache.m
At revision 4544

SICCI for Xcode: build environment check started

FATAL: SICCI for Xcode: keychain credentials not set

Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must configure SICCI keychain credentials in Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global.  Not mentioned in documentation at http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=53608642.